# How to get notified of a user crediting their wallet on Paystack – Virtual Account

Tags: php, integration, paystack

When integrating a virtual account, on Paystack I understand you need to create customer data and then a dedicated virtual account (DVA) before connecting to that customer, of course, I would have a record of that virtual account on our end too.

If this user should credit the virtual account how would I know?

What is the webhook I’ll be listening for, I went through the list of webhooks available and I cannot find which of them exactly is responsible for informing me that customer with X ID credited their wallet

Find the URL to the webhook below;
https://paystack.com/docs/payments/webhooks/#types-of-events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just check the Create Virtual Account Number documentation, there is a webhook section on that for **charge.success** there are keys to check for if transaction is for Virtual wallet